# Informatica: configure domain (error PCSF_46008. cannot connect to domain)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, informatica

I have problem with configure domain.

I installed Informatica 10.4 (server part) on VirtualBox (Linux)
and client on Windows.

When I try configure domen (in Repository Manager), it appears error

> PCSF_46008. Cannot connect to domain.

```
Domain Name: Domain_sandbox
Getaway Host: 127.0.0.5
Getaway Port: 6005
```

How fix it?

on Linux side:

`ifconfig:  10.0.2.15`

Node>General properties>Port: 6005

```
VirtualBox Port Forwarding rules:
127.0.0.5 6005 - 10.0.2.15 6005
127.0.0.5 6008 - 10.0.2.15 6008
127.0.0.5 6015 - 10.0.2.15 6015
127.0.0.5 6016 - 10.0.2.15 6016
```

Firewall on Linux is disabled.

Inforamatica serves is running
Oracle services is running

From Windows I can connet to Admin panel http//127.0.0.5:6008
and when I try  http//127.0.0.5:6005/coreservices/DomainConfigurationService I recive answer:
DomainService/InitTime : Sat Jun 12 09:53:59 MSK 2021
but when  I try connect from Repository Manager I have error.

also  `$ infacmd.sh ListServices -dn Domain_sandbox` returns:

```
PC_RS  (Repositoru service)
Rest_Operations_Hub
Resource_Manager_Service
Email_Service
Scheduler_Service
PC_IS
```

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to understand, your infa setup is all fine - repo service, integration service is fine. But you can not connect to Infa from Windows client.  Since some specific ports are blocked in Linux, you can not connect to Infa. Infa normally uses a range of ports - details below. In summary, you can open 6001 to 6200 to only the windows server you are working on.
Could you please open all of them?

Here are default ports that infa uses -

- Node - 6005
- Service Manager port - 6006/6007
- Infa admin - 6008/6009
- Application services like Repo manager/repo admin uses a range of ports dynamically -  Default is 6014 to 6114.

Also, pls note to open other ports like for other applications.
The following services use static port numbers:

- Analyst Service. Default is 8085 for HTTP.
- Content Management
  Service. Default is 8105 for HTTP.
- Data Integration Service. Default
  is 8095 for HTTP.
- Metadata Manager Service. Default is 10250 for
  HTTP. Search Service. Default is 8084 for HTTP.
- Web Services Hub. Default is 7333 for HTTP.

Comment: i opend all ports from 6000 to 6200 and 7333,8084,8085,8095,8105,10250. but it didn`t help.

Comment: can you ping the linux server(if pingable) from windows?

Comment: so, i changed network settings to 'Virtual Host Adapter'. On the linux side i found ip ('ip route show' : dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.101. Ping from windows to this ip work, links  192.168.56.101:6008/administrator, 192.168.56.101:5500/em  work but domain from the repository manager takes error

Comment: if i follow the link  http://192.168.56.101:6005 from windows browser it redirets to link http://<linux_host_name>:6008  with error page.

Comment: not sure whats happening, Are TCP/IP ports open? if you try to open admin console from windows - its working - right ? If not, then i think there is some issue in port opening process.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it!

I put guest ip in "Edit Domain" panel

```
Getaway Host: 127.0.0.5
Gataway Port: 6005
```

i takes error pcsf_46008  and the parameter "Getaway Host" changes to Linux Host name.

```
Getaway Host: ol8.localdomain
Gataway Port: 6005
```

I set parameters on Virtual Box:

```
VirtualBox Port Forwarding rules:
127.0.0.5 6005 - 10.0.2.15 6005
```

It doesn`t help

But then i wrote

`127.0.0.5 ol8.localdomain ol8`

in hosts file on Windows.
and it works.